# Creating 2D polygons in XNA

Tags: xna, collision-detection

I am trying to implement collisions using the separating axis theorem. However All I have ever used in terms of polygons is the Rectangle class included in XNA already. How can I make multi-sided polygons?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw triangles directly using [DrawUserIndexedPrimitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196409%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) and other similar functions.  Yes, it is much more work than simply drawing rectangles.

Example code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx

Comment: This is good but I am looking more for a function I can use to draw multi sided polygons, not just triangles

Comment: @Roger There is no such thing built into the XNA framework.  You could build something to do it for you, of course.  But no matter what you do, a polygon would need to be defined in terms of its component triangles; that's the only format the GPU can process.

Comment: I think the user's question is more to do with collision detection. Question for the user: Are you expecting your polygons to have concave sections? (so that if you're following along its boundary: Do you ever turn "left" instead of right?) This may affect what kinds of collision detection you can use .

Comment: @Katana314 I thought the same thing, actually.  But that (implicit) question is "how do I do SAT collision physics?", which is too broadly scoped to be answerable, so I ignored it on purpose.  I also assumed that any half-hearted implementation of those collisions would have vertex data available.

Comment: @Katana314 Yes I am trying to implement SAT collision following a tutorial if found but its written in AS3. This is the example I am following and trying to replicate on XNA http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/diagrams/tutA_demo.html. The problem is I'm still pretty new at this and I don't know how to make any other shapes other than rectangles